# Storing value and Retrieve to other page Using Session

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have two page, one is displaying data and another is having input field. I wish to on page load it save the value and retrieve it in second page. i have try many time but in second page i am not able to retrieve session value. Below Example.

Code:-

first.html

```
    <div class="success_bx">
         <p >Your Application id is : SSP2019021700040906</p>
         <p>Your Password is : 6QANDV</p>
    </div>
```

Second.html

```
<div class="login">
<input type="text" name="username" id="user_name" required="" class="form-control my_inpt" >
```

Script.js

```
var one= $(".success_bx p:eq(0)").text().split(" : ")[1];

 localStorage.setItem("username",one);
  //console.log(one);
  retrieve = document.getElementById('user_name');
  retrieve.value = localStorage.getItem("username");
  //console.log(retrieve);
```

Comment: retrive=getElementById('user_name'); In this line you missed document.getElementById('user_name');

Comment: ya. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Just use getitem method to fetch the value from localstorage

```
retrieve = localStorage.getItem("username");
```